# Should I change from fluorescent to LED lighting in the kitchen?

Tags: electrical, lighting, kitchens

I bought an old home and put two large 14 in. round fluorescent lights up, thinking it would supply plenty of light. There's also a recessed light over the sink. It's still dark in there. I've been advised to check out Lithonia lighting and get LED lights to replace. Please tell me what you think would be best. I was told that the fixtures in the big box stores were not as good.

Comment: Are you saying that the lights are dim, or they are too small?  Your light fixture's ballast is probably bad and needs replacement.

Comment: Unfortunately you have too many variables. Pitcures would come in handy, and or a drawing of the layout of the room with dimensions,

Comment: Hmm. Beware the salesdroids - Lithonia just happens to be what HD (and Lowes?) sell a lot of since they don't stock other brands. Look with a broader focus than that. I'd suggest starting with a paintjob to the whitest white you can find on every painted surface in the kitchen...can make a big difference regardless of the fixtures chosen.

Answer (score 2):

14in light is a useless figure. What you're looking for is lumens. ("Replaces a X watt incandescent" is also useful, though affected by marketing a bit.) Get a target lumen value, then get a lighting setup that meets this value. LEDs vs fluorescents doesn't matter for getting enough light, just for power-saving purposes.

Before you replaced the lights, was it bright enough? If so, calculate how much lighting there was back then, and try to hit that same amount.